# How can i see this RUN_CMD defined

Tags: linux

Inside my Shell Script , i have this line present

```
RUN_CMD="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -cp $CLASSPATH  com/mypack/BalanceRunner
```

Could anybody please tell me , what is meant by this command RUN_CMD 
and where can i see this RUN_CMD defined

Thanks for reading

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414811/how-to-see-shell-scripts-variables-defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the definition of `RUN_CMD` variable. (although it requires an `"` to the end of the line).